# why can a class call a magic method from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, magic-methods

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("init called")

    def some_method(self):
        print("some method called")
```

Why can a class call the constructor of another class when an object of the class that owns the function is passed as an argument.
For example, `str` calling the `__init__` method of the `Example` class. The following line runs smoothly

```
str.__init__(Example())
```

but when i use `str` to call a non-magic method, in this case `some_method`,

```
str.some_method(Example())
```

it shows the following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'some_method'
```

I understand class methods shouldn't be used this way but i'd like to know the cause of this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.__init__(Example())` is calling the `__init__` method of `str`. The only reason `Example`'s `__init__` is running is because the code `Example()` runs it. So, `str.some_method(Example())` fails because `str` has no method called `some_method`. You're not somehow making `str` call `some_method` on an instance of `Example`. That's not how Python's syntax works whatsoever. In both cases you're trying to call a method of `str` itself. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but maybe `str(Example().some_method())` is more like what you want.